# The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-sqlite, flipper

This is a knowledge sharing question.

I have a react-native project with `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` set to `30`.
After upgrading expo version and related packages android app was not getting built.
The following error was appearing in logs:

```
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.2.0.
AAR metadata file: /home/<MY USERNAME>/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f7bf6c20b6aaa8d6365a0aa8e2ddf180/sqlite-framework-2.2.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

Spent lot of time trying to figure out what's the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was facebook flipper.
I have upgraded flipper from version `0.54.0` to `0.129.0` in `android/gradle.properties`.
Looks like this problem was introduced in version `0.128.0`.
Setting the version to `0.127.0` solved this issue.

However it introduced another issue. On Macbook pro with M1, emulator was crashing with null pointer dereference error.

So I had to downgrade flipper to `0.125.0`.